# Native Library Load Order in Unity Plugin For Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, plugins, shared-libraries, native

I am developing a Unity plugin for Android platform. I have a couple of *.so files and the application needs to load these libraries in a certain order. How can I manage this load order in an Unity Plugin structure?
Currently, I just drag and drop the shared libraries into Plugin directory but I have no idea what is going on during Application startup and the program just crashes.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I can see from the internet around Unity forum and support, people prefer not to use dependable .so's or use custom plugins loader. I have just faced a similar problem with linux plugins. By the way, windows plugins with few dlls work like a charm